# COUNT is grouping rows unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

Table `items` keeps track of the different types of items that can be stocked.

```
item_type  item_name  last_stock

   1         cake      2010-08-10
   2         fruit     2010-08-07
   3         soda      2010-08-07
   4         water     2010-08-09
```

Table `individual_items` keeps track of each specific item.

```
   id   item_type

    1          1 
    2          2        
    3          1
```

My query in MySQL:

```
SELECT i.item_type, i.item_name, COUNT(j.id)
FROM items i
LEFT OUTER JOIN individual_items j
ON i.item_type = j.item_type
GROUP BY j.item_type
```

However, the `COUNT(j.id)` is screwing with my result. It appears to be grouping any items that are defined but not actually in existence.

```
item_type    item_name  COUNT(j.id)
    1           cake         2
    2           fruit        1
    3           soda         0
```

I think the expected fourth row `4 water 0` is not appearing because `COUNT()` is incorrectly grouping the non-existent rows that result from the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should group by all fields in your SELECT statement except those in aggregative functions

```
SELECT i.item_type, i.item_name, COUNT(j.id)
FROM items i
LEFT OUTER JOIN individual_items j
ON i.item_type = j.item_type
GROUP BY i.item_type, i.item_name
```

update: I've tested on my local mysql server, the code above should work

Answer (score 1):

Your `GROUP BY` clause is probably the culprit here. You're grouping by the table that may not contain an item type, so in the case of item type 3 and 4, j.item_type is NULL (while i.item_type would contain the expected values). The problem should fix itself if you group by the item_type on i instead.

Comment: Because for both item_type 3 and item_type 4, j.item_type has the same value - NULL. MySQL is grouping those two rows together because they share a common group-by value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a RIGHT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT i.item_type, i.item_name, COUNT(j.id)
FROM items i
LEFT OUTER JOIN individual_items j
ON i.item_type = j.item_type
GROUP BY i.item_type,i.item_name
```

Comment: this will output count 1 for item_type 3 and 4 too. you should use COUNT(j.id)